# How can I align an element according to its background?

Tags: html, css

I want to align the following text to center of its background.

```css
h1{
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
  }
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **text-align:center** to center the element to it's background

```css
h1{
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use text-align for alignment of your text.You can use text-align:center in your tag**

```css
h1{
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
  }
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

```css
h1{
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, we can do it by using text align......  :P

```css
h1{
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
  }
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: you posted this comment as an answer